# Is there a more efficient way to calculate highest and lowest balances in the last 12 months?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have an array of every transaction for the last 12 months, over a number of accounts. My current process provides the highest and lowest overall balances for each of the last 12 complete months and is timing-out in another piece of software before the transformation is completed, is there a quicker way I've not thought of?

My current process:

1. Create an array for the last 13 months
2. find the overall current balance
3. cycle through each transaction and push the balance at the time into a balances array within the given month
4. For each month, use .map to determine the highest and lowest balance. Slice to only return 12 "full" months.

```js
exports.main = async({
  accounts,
  transactions
}) => {
  const monthNames = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];

  const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
  const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

  // Create an array with entries for each of the last 13 months
  const months = Array.from({
    length: 13
  }, (_, i) => {
    const date = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth - i, 1);
    const monthName = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
    const yearName = date.getFullYear();

    return {
      monthName: monthName,
      yearName: yearName,
      balances: []
    };
  });


  // Calculate daily closing balances and group by month
  let currentBalance = accounts.map(acc => (acc.balance.current)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  transactions.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.postedDate) - new Date(a.postedDate));

  transactions.forEach(tr => {
    let originalDate = (tr.postedDate).slice(0, 10);
    let monthName = new Date(originalDate).toLocaleString("en-GB", {
      month: "long"
    });
    let yearName = new Date(originalDate).getFullYear();
    if (tr.amount !== 0) {
      currentBalance += tr.amount
    }
    let month = months.find(
      (m) => m.monthName === monthName && m.yearName === yearName);
    // If balance is in the last 12 month store the balance
    if (month) {
      month.balances.push({
        date: originalDate,
        balance: currentBalance,
      });
    }


  });

  // Calculate highest and lowest closing balances for each of the last 13 months

  months.forEach(month => {
    if (month.balances.length > 0) {

      let highestUtilisation = Math.max.apply(Math, month.balances.map(bal => bal.balance));
      highestUtilisation = Math.round(highestUtilisation * 100) / 100

      let lowestUtilisation = Math.min.apply(Math, month.balances.map(bal => bal.balance));
      lowestUtilisation = Math.round(lowestUtilisation * 100) / 100,

        month.highestUtilisation = highestUtilisation,
        month.lowestUtilisation = lowestUtilisation

    }
  });

  return {
    months: months.slice(1)
  };

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+highest+lowest+balances+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please [edit] it to make it a [mcve] - if you are just looking to improve the code, then perhaps code review is a better site

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: A potential improvement will be to keep each month statistics and reuse it- no need to recalculate,  since ONLY current month may change the result. Roughly you can save ~90% of calculations.

Comment: you could provide real data like `accounts` so the code would work

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of unnecassary work here

1. depending on the format of `postedDate` of your transaction, you may not need to parse it to a date to make it comparable. If it's not `YYYY-MM-DD` can you adapt your datasource to make it so? This probably will make sorting your transactions faster
2. instead of `months` being an array, where you have to search for the correct month for each and every transaction, make it a map, where the key consists of `YYYY-MM` so you can access the correct month directly
3. in your transactionhandling you are parsing your `orignalDate` string even *twice* only to get some information, you probably can get from the string itself. Ie, instead of the name of the month you can use its number in the key of the map. If you really need the month's name in your ouput, do this translation as last step ...
4. when you calculate the lowest and the highest balance, you go over each `month.balance` four times (ie you call `map` twice, and `min` and `max` once each). You can do this in a single for loop

   ```
    let max = Number.MIN_VALUE, min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    month.balances.forEach(b => {
      max = Math.max(max, b.balance);
      min = Math.min(min, b.balance);
    })
   ```
5. simple `for .. of` loops are (most of the time) more efficient than `forEach` But you have to do benchmarks if that's really the case in your app ...

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a map for the months: As your transactions are already sorted by date, keep a reference to the month-entry last used. If the year and month for the next transaction is the same as the previous, you don't need to search for it again. You will only need to search the array when month or year changes ...

Finally, I don't know where you are running this and how many changes happen for the past, but if changes only occur for the current month (and maybe the month before) can you keep your previously calculated data anywhere, so you don't have to recaculate everything from scratch even if it did not change?